# How to provide a dynamic (calculated) css property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am working on task in which each time a user scrolls or resizes the screen I would like to recalculate a css properties for an element.

Let's say I want to impl. a progress bar and the progress is reported based on the scroll position in the window

```
<div class='progress-bar-wrap'>
   <div class='progress-bar-progress'></div>
</div>

function updateScrollProgress () {
   this.progressIndicator.css('width', this.calculateProgressBarWidth() + 'px');
}
```

I tried to hook on scroll and resize events, but this seem to have a laggy effect.

```
window.on('scroll', updateScrollProgress)
window.on('resize', updateScrollProgress)
```

I tried in the scroll and resize event handlers to requestAnimationFrame

```
window.on('scroll', function(){window.requestAnimationFrame( updateScrollProgress))
window.on('resize', function(){window.requestAnimationFrame( updateScrollProgress))
```

And experienced huge improvement in most browsers, however it is yet occasionally laggy.

I tried to request another frame, when from the requestAnimationFrame handler:

```
function updateScrollProgress () {
   window.requestAnimationFrame( updateScrollProgress)
   this.progressIndicator.css('width', this.calculateProgressBarWidth() + 'px');
}
```

This completely eliminated the laggy effect, but comes to the cost of endless loop of calls to this method, even when no recalculations are needed.

Is there a way to hook a handler just before the browser decides to draw element(s), so that I can provide/set the those "dynamic" css values for a property?

Comment: If you've gotten rid of the lag, why is the handler being called "too often"? Usually, "too often" in this context means "is causing lag" (by running too often and thus slowing things down).

Answer (score 1):

What's what you're doing when you use `requestAnimationFrame`. If you've gotten rid of the lag using it, it's unclear why you say the function is running "too often." Usually in this sort of context, "too often" means "is causing lag" (by running too often and slowing things down). If yours isn't, then...?

If you want the handler called less often, you can debounce it, but then you'll probably notice delays before the changes you want (because you've debounced), which it sounds like is what you're trying to avoid.

In any case, `requestAnimationFrame` is, for now at least, the right tool for the "just before the browser renders the frame" job.

Comment: Ok, I will provide some example code. The thing is that I would like to somehow provide a different css value, just before the browser is deciding to render. Let's say I would like the height to be a function of the document scroll position for instance

Comment: @Nas - That's what `requestAnimationFrame` is: A callback just before the browser renders a frame.

Comment: But when to hook?? And execute only when a reflow of the elements is there

Comment: @Nas - Whenever you need to make a change. So if this is all based on scrolling, I'd hook the scroll event, do the calculation, and if the value is different from the last value I've used, I'd schedule a rAF callback to use that new value, and remember I'd used it. If that's too laggy for you, then waiting for the scroll event is apparently too late. If so, just always being in the rAF cycle (hooking it on load and rehooking every time) is what you'll have to do. Keep the calculation as short as possible, but it's once every 16.6ms on average where your function is probably running in micros..

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately endless loop of rAF callbacks yields the best results for now..
I was wondering if I can hook it right before the browser need to redraw and element as alternative to endless loop..

Comment: @Nas - Again, that's what you're doing when you call rAF (but only on a full-page level, I think I may see what you mean about an element-specific callback). It would appear that for whatever reason, the `scroll` event is happening too late for you, hence the `scroll`+rAF not being good neough. There's some work being done on extension points *within* the rendering stuff, but it's at least a couple of years off. I wish I could find the page I was reading about it on to show you...

Comment: Well I noticed that when I do the options with the endless looping and do a console log the code gets constantly being executed. 

So What I want is not to always request another frame, but whenever for some reason a new reflow is triggered - when something causes a redrawing to hook my code..

Comment: So basically I do not want to request animation frame. I want animation frame to request me :P

Comment: @Nas :-) Which is, I believe, exactly the kind of hook being considered. Drat, I wish I could find that page...

Comment: Hope it will make it through. Unfortunately I failed to find such/similar hook to get the job done at this point. But thanks for trying with me :)

Comment: @Nas - **Found it**: https://drafts.css-houdini.org/worklets/ I haven't had a chance to read it yet and so it may not be relevant to your problem, but...

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your event function through a debounce function:

More info on debounce functions here:

https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};

var myEfficientFn = debounce(function() {
  // All the taxing stuff you do
}, 250);

window.addEventListener('resize', myEfficientFn);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to remove the laggy effect, unfortunately debouncing it will have the opposite effect :(

Comment: the lag is usually caused by the event handler being called several times a second so debouncing usually fixes this, for me at least.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case the lag is caused by handler being called late. Unfortunately debouncing will only make the call to be even later and hence prolong the lag :(